# Valid ways of saying a fraction using (saying) cardinal number as its denominator

Tags: grammatical-number, fractions

Suppose we have a fraction: 23 / 100.
Using cardinal way of saying a fraction, which of the following is spoken colloquially?
I believe I listed all possible ways (valid and invalid) of saying a fraction using cardinal numbers.

- [a] twenty three hundredth
- [b] twenty three hundredth**s**
- [c] twenty three **one** hundredth
- [d] twenty three **one** hundredth**s**
- [e] twenty three **a** hundredth
- [f] twenty three **a** hundredth**s**

*Note: These are permutations of using ("", "one", "a") and (singular vs plural form of the denominator).*

I believe, without **a** or **one** in the denominator leads to confusion:

- case [a] with 2300th
- case [b] with 20 / 300

Lastly the plural form of the denominator is used only when the numerator itself is plural (> 1).
It does not matter what the denominator is (i.e. *x* / **100**, *x* / **123**, *x* / **200**, *x* / **234** ...).

I greatly appreciate it if someone could clarify.

Comment: You're never going to get a single answer. I *personally* read it as [b]. But that doesn't mean much. Or I might say *23 over a hundred*, a variation that you don't list.

Comment: I say “23 over 100”.

Comment: To Jason and Xanne, thank you for both of your comments. I personally like using the word "over" and say the numerator and the denominator in an ordinal manner, myself. But this time, I wanted to omit those variations and focus when the denominator is said in cardinal way (i.e. -st, -nd, -rd, -th).

Comment: Whoa... you're already supposing too much with your first sentence. By asking how to express the fraction in words, you beg the question of whether to state the quantity as a fraction at all, rather than decimally (.23 or 0.23) or as a percentage (23%). In your example fraction, the denominator is 100, which makes me suspicious -- of all integers the denominator could be, how come it is 100?  What is the *context*? Is the quantity really one that has been rounded to two decimal places? If so, "point two three" or "nought point two three" would be better.

Comment: @RosieF Thank you for your comment. The denominator of 100 was an unfortunate bad example. However in the case of 1/1000000, I would say `one one millionth` (case [c]) for cardinal form. That way, it is unambiguous and I believe the fraction way of saying is concise. However, I wanted to know if there are other valid ways of saying it that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I think B: *twenty three hundredths* and D: *twenty three one hundredths* are the only ones that you could say and *sound* correct.  There is the possibility of being misunderstood but people are rather used to that and look for clarification. One would only use *hundred**th*** as a singular to say *One hundredth* as in "one and only one hundredth" since the *One* is itself singular. A hundredth or one or two one-hundredths is enough by itself.

Comment: Thank you @Elliot. From your reply I understood that case B might lead to misunderstanding (`23 / 100` vs `20 / 300`). I also understood that it is the numerator that decides whether cardinal denominator is singular or plural. However, there is one part I did not understand in your comment. What did you mean by the last sentence: `A hundredth or one or two one-hundredths is enough by itself`. Could you clarify?

Comment: Not sure I recall myself. In C and E you are saying twenty three a/one hundredth. I only meant that the singular hundredth is only correct as one, never more than one. When you say three one hundredth you should be using plural as in three one hundredth*S*.
People often ask, or go away grumbling, about the details of such fractions as spoken. Usually the context of a previous calculation gives the likely answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will entirely depend on context and the listener’s familiarity. Here are some example sentences that I, as a mathematician, might say:

> I have twenty three hundredths of a pie.

> I have twenty three of a hundred cards.

> I only finished twenty three percent of the test.

> ... if you then divide by seven, you end up with twenty three over one hundred.

In a verbal context (and I assume you have meant one that matches my first example), it would be important to provide emphasis to tip off the listener to your meaning.

> I have twenty *pause* three hundredths of a pie. (20/300)

> I have twenty three *pause* hundredths of a pie. (23/100)

Comment: I believe it would be “I have twenty [pause] three-hundredths” for 20/300 with a hyphen, no?

Comment: Sure, but I don’t remember the last time a hyphen was audible.

Comment: Well, as long as you’re writing it out....

Comment: @IanMacDonald, so you picked case [b] (23/100 = `twenty three hundredths`). Any confusion when spoken is clarified by pausing at an appropriate place (where `/` is in a fraction) to distinguish 23/100 vs 20/300. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish In formal writing, I think the hyphen goes between tens and ones position.
If that is the case, then I agree that 23/100 (`twenty-three hundredths`) is distinguished from 20/300 (`twenty three hundredths`).
However when the wording does not have a hyphen then there will be a confusion like `eleven hundredths` (11/100 vs 1/1100).